# How to produce a cotton box in Learning Factory?

Tags: learning-factory

At some time exploring the Alpha Version of the [Learning Factory](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1150090) I've stuck at the moment where yarn balls could be regularly produced from the cotton and be sold by the cat shop, which generated some income. But to complete my selling and producing queue (and to automate it) I must somehow produce a cotton box for a cotton picker. The science lab is connected with optic cable to the cat shop, but I can't produce any receipt. In the cat monument I also can't choose any receipt to study. To understand what is going on you could see the screenshot of my "pipeline". [image: pipeline]

So my questions are:

1. How should I connect the given resources so I can move along?
2. How can I use generated income from the store to let the science cat produce new articles?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [developers response on steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1150090/discussions/0/2965016081061890351/) we have an answer:

1. To produce a cotton box you should just place the cotton picker nearby cotton tree like you can see it on screenshot.[image]
2. Generated income will be automatically used by a science lab if the later is connected to the cat store via optical cable.